# Select last entry for every user from log table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have problem with sql that is suppose to select last log entry per user for many users.
This is sample how my table looks like

```
user_id |   date
--------------------
    1       2013-03-06 10:00:00
    17      2013-03-06 11:00:00
    2       2013-03-06 10:00:00
    5       2013-03-06 10:00:00
    1       2013-03-06 11:00:00
    17      2013-03-06 13:00:00
    17      2013-03-06 13:01:00
    2       2013-03-06 14:01:00
    2       2013-03-06 15:00:00
    2       2013-03-06 18:01:00
```

The result of this query is suppose to be

```
user_id |   date
--------------------
    1       2013-03-06 11:00:00
    2       2013-03-06 18:01:00
    5       2013-03-06 10:00:00
    17      2013-03-06 13:01:00
```

For now I'm using this query

```
SELECT 
    a.user_id,
    (SELECT b.date FROM alerts.alerts_log as b WHERE b.user_id = a.user_id ORDER BY b.date DESC LIMIT 1) as date
FROM 
    alerts.alerts_log  as a
WHERE 
    a.user_id IN  (1,2,5,17) 
GROUP BY a.user_id
```

but I dont thiknk its the best one because will be too slow for many records...
can you pls suggest me better one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id , MAX(date)
FROM alerts.alerts_log
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 4):

if you have only two columns in the table, the query below will suffice your needs,

```
SELECT  user_ID, MAX(date) max_date
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY user_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02ddf/1)

but if not and you want to get all columns within the row, you need to have subquery which separately gets the maximum date per `user_ID`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  user_ID, MAX(date) max_date
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY user_ID
        ) b ON a.user_ID = b.user_ID AND
                a.date = b.max_date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27dd5/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the link to SQLFiddle Demo, but I checked his answer because I think he was first.

Comment: Hello John, how should be the query if we have the same situation (last entry - max date) over 5 tables. That means my select statement contains fields from 5 tables and I have from t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 inner join ...... where .....   ?